# Moving around a differential

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $f(x)$ is a real-valued differential univariate function.

Consider a measure of sensitivity of this function with respect to a point $x$ in the domain.

$$s(x)=\frac{x\frac{df(x)}{dx}}{f(x)}.$$

My questions #1: Why is it legal to move around the differential in the following form?

$$\frac{\frac{df(x)}{f(x)}}{\frac{dx}{x}}.$$

My question #2: When is it illegal to do this?

My question #3: Why is the second form an expression of a percent change in $f(x)$ in the numerator and a percent change in $x$ in the denominator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $$s_f(x)=x\left(\frac1{f}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)(x)=x\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln\circ{f}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)(x)=x\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln\circ{f}}{\mathrm{d}\ln}\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)(x)=x\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln\circ{f}}{\mathrm{d}\ln}\right)(x)\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)(x)=x\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln\circ{f}}{\mathrm{d}\ln}\right)(x)\frac1{x}=\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln\circ{f}}{\mathrm{d}\ln}\right)(x).$$ So far, this is all valid, and it includes merely using the chain rule. $$s_f(x)=\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln\circ{f}}{\mathrm{d}\ln}\right)(x)=\frac{(\mathrm{d}\ln\circ{f})(x)}{(\mathrm{d}\ln)(x)}=\frac{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{f}\right)(x)}{\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\right)(x)}=\frac{\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{f(x)}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}}.$$
Every step in this derivation is valid, except for one step, and one step only. The problematic step is $$\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln\circ{f}}{\mathrm{d}\ln}\right)(x)=\frac{(\mathrm{d}\ln\circ{f})(x)}{(\mathrm{d}\ln)(x)}.$$ You cannot treat a derivative operator as a fraction of differential forms, because differential forms are not multiplicatively invertible. Nonetheless, this invalid step does "accidentally" result in the correct answer, and it smoothly allows you to go from $$x\left(\frac1{f}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)(x)$$ to $$\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln\circ{f}}{\mathrm{d}\ln}\right)(x).$$ The reason behind these illegal manipulations giving the correct result is because although you cannot actually divide differential forms, it turns out that there is a bijection that maps the differential form $df$ to the derivative of $f.$ This bijection occurs because differential forms carry a vector space, and so, for the coordinate basis $\{\mathrm{d}x\},$ the coefficients with respect to that basis for any given vector $df.$ This stays true in higher dimensions.

Comment: Angle, thanks for the response. Is the circle for the composition or chain rule? Just a point of clarification.

Comment: The circle is composition. It means $(\ln\circ{f})(x)=\ln[f(x)],$ and so $(\ln\circ{f})'(x)=\frac1{f(x)}f'(x).$

Comment: Thanks! it clears up a lot!